# Android: ListView causing requestLayout() to be improperly called

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-logcat

Having fast scroll enabled in my ListView is causing the following error:

`08-09 01:47:33.294  10816-10816/com.exampleW/View﹕ requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.TextView{...} during layout: running second layout pass`

I know the ListView is causing the problem because removing the following line of code from the ListView's XML removes the error:

```
android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
```

Is there any way to fix this error? To be thorough, I have also included the TextView's XML:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Are you using any custom views or have any layout listeners?

Answer (score 0):

i think this error is not because of android:fastScrollEnabled="true" however try below code in your java file..

try list.smoothScrollToPosition(0);  also  with android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
so that data appears when scroll is called...

something like this..

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
 {
          @Override
          public void run()
          {
              list.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
          }
 }, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is known bug in android implementation when you set fastScrollEnabled = true, which appears in some android versions.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75516

Apart from the ugly console spamming with the debug message from above, there seem to be no other impacts (maybe performance in some cases, which I haven't tested).